# Concurrent sorted task executor that catches Exception in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Given N lists of Ni elements, I need to call a given method for each element:

```
process(element);
```

processing all Ni elements for each list in order, and, once finished, I have to know which elements have been processed and which have thrown an Exception.

Is there any already implemented executor that can get a list of tasks, will process them in order and will keep track of failures?

Comment: Although it's not exactly what you are looking for but, you can have a look at the invokeAll() method of ExecutorService.

Comment: What do you mean by *'in order'*? Is it possible to start processing a new list while the previous one hasn't been fully processed yet? Is it possible to start processing a new item of a list if a previous item hasn't been processed yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Long answer: no, because it's easily achieved in less than 20 lines of code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {


    List<Integer> elements = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    List<Future<Integer>> results = elements.stream().map((e) -> {

        return executor.submit(() -> {
            // Fail for even numbers
            if (e % 2 == 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }

            return e;
        });

    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    results.forEach((e) -> {
        try {
            System.out.println(e.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e1) {
            System.out.println(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Will output:

```
1
false
3
5
false
13
```